# Ubuntu is not working/booting when I switch on my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a Dell Laptop. I was upgrading my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 but due to some errors the installation stopped or halted and then nothing was responding. I restarted my laptop and I get GRUB Menu.

[image]

I have 4 options now:

1. Ubuntu (when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the Caps Lock LED starts blinking and nothing happens afterwards)
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu (Recovery mode is also not working)
3. System setup
4. Restore Ubuntu 14.04 to factory setup

I don’t want to factory reset as I don’t want to lose data.
What should I do now?

Comment: The blinking caps light means the kernel crashed. At the GRUB menu, select `Advanced Options` and select the 2nd newest kernel, and see if it boots. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: I have several options to boot in Advanced option but nothing happening. When i hit enter on recovery mode some lines are executing and then it says KERNEL PANIC NOT SYNCING- KlLL INIT. 
I don’t know what should i do now @heynnema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what went wrong, but there are a few options that can be attempted to fix the issue, here are 2 easy options:

- Boot up from USB and try to re-install ubuntu 16.04 (upgrade option section)
- Boot up from USB and try to fix GRUB (bootup repair section)

### Upgrade Option

- Boot up to the Ubuntu USB
- Click "Install Ubuntu"
- Select "Upgrade Ubuntu" option from the options given
- Click "Install Now"

### Bootup Repair

- Boot up to the Ubuntu USB
- Click "Try Ubuntu"
- Run the following commands to install boot-repair:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair -y
boot-repair
```

- With the last command, boot-repair will start scanning for problems and will eventually pop up a dialog
- Click "Recommended repair"
- Follow any instructions given
- When done, reboot

Comment: Can you please help me with steps I should take to get backup of my data. Reinstalling will likely erase all my data right?

Comment: Upgrading should not remove your data, if you're worried, you can always boot up to live USB and then copy the files from your drive to an external one though, just make sure not to select the format option on your home partition (or root partition if you don't have a separate home partition)